# Enable Cookies for reverse Proxy and Apache2

Tags: web, cookies, apache2, reverse-proxy, tomcat9

i try to access an application on a tomcat server via a reverse proxy and apache2.
The reverse proxy is working just fine, but the application throws an error, that cookies are disabled.

I googled but nothing helped.
My vhost.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

     ServerName testcms.mydomain.de

     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
     DocumentRoot /var/www/cms

     ProxyPreserveHost On

     ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/opencms/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/opencms/ 


     ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain http://localhost:8080/opencms testcms.mydomain.de
     ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /cms/Cookies

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =testcms.mydomain.de
     RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName testcms.mydomain.de

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/cms

        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/opencms/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/opencms/ 
        ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain 127.0.0.1:8080/opencms/ testcms.mydomain.de
        ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /cms/cookies

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/testcms.mydomain.de/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/testcms.mydomain.de/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

The ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain and ProxyPassReverseCookiePath should help, but they dont.
Did I miss something while implementing the reverse proxy?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: it just sas cookies are not enabled (the ErrorMessage comes from a Software called OpenCMS)

Comment: Can you post the error message here? I am familiar in OpenCms.